# First order ODE: $y'=\frac{b\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-ay}{ax}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the ODE

$$y'=\frac{b\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-ay}{ax}$$

I've tried the substitution $ y = x u(x) = ux$ but, even ignoring the modulus of x, I was't able to solve it. Any other suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: As you already know the "correct" substitution you should go ahead and solve the resulting equation for $u(x)$ via separation of the variables.

Comment: I tried, but I couldnt solve the integral

Comment: the integral is far from easy but then maybe you should add to your question what you have done and present the integral such that people can help you with that...

Comment: I added with this tag because the given answer is different from which I've obtained even asking wolfram to solve it. Maybe I am trying to solve the wrong integral.

Comment: I think I have a solution for you. The integral takes several steps, and is not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how far we can get using that substitution:
$$LET: y=ux \rightarrow y'=u'x+u$$
Therefore:
$$y'=\frac{b\sqrt{x^2+(ux)^2}-aux}{ax}=\frac{b\sqrt{x^2+u^2x^2}aux}{ax}=\frac{bx\sqrt{1+u^2}-aux}{ax}$$
$$=\frac{b\sqrt{1+u^2}-a}{a}=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1+u^2}-1$$
Substitute on the left-hand side:
$$u'x+u=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1+u^2}-1 \rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}\cdot x+u=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1+u^2}-1$$
We can separate the variables:
$$\frac{x}{dx}=\frac{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1+u^2}-1-u}{du}$$
Take the reciprocal for a more canonical form:
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1+u^2}-1-u}$$
Left-hand side integration is trivial $\ln(x)$, so let's focus on the right-hand side. Without loss of generality, we can say:$k=\frac{b}{a}$. Trying trig substitution:
$$LET :u=\tan^2(\theta) \rightarrow du=2\tan(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$$
$$\frac{du}{k\sqrt{1+u^2}-1-u}=\frac{2\tan(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)d\theta}{k\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)}-(1+\tan^2(\theta))}$$
$$=\frac{2\tan(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)d\theta}{k\sec(\theta)-\sec^2(\theta)}$$
To remove the quadratic in terms of $\sec(\theta)$, let's divide the numerator, and the denominator by $\sec^2(\theta)$. Remember that $\sec(\theta)=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$.
$$=\frac{2\tan(\theta)d\theta}{\frac{k}{\sec(\theta)}-1}=\frac{2\tan(\theta)d\theta}{k\cos(\theta)-1}=\frac{2\sin(\theta)d\theta}{k\cos^2(\theta)-\cos(\theta)}$$
Let's try completing the square, so first make the leading coefficient i nthe denominator a $1$.
$$=\frac{2\frac{1}{k}\sin(\theta)d\theta}{\cos^2(\theta)-\frac{1}{k}\cos(\theta)}$$
$$=\frac{2\frac{1}{k}\sin(\theta)d\theta}{\cos^2(\theta)-\frac{1}{k}\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{4k^2}-\frac{1}{4k^2}}$$
$$=\frac{2\frac{1}{k}\sin(\theta)d\theta}{(\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2k})^2-(\frac{1}{2k})^2}$$
Now try another $v$ substitution. $v=\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2k}\rightarrow dv=-\sin(\theta)d\theta$.
$$=\frac{-2\frac{1}{k}dv}{(v)^2-(\frac{1}{2k})^2}=\frac{\frac{-2}{k}dv}{(v-\frac{1}{2k})\cdot(v+\frac{1}{2k})}$$
This formula can be expanded using partial fraction decomposition.
$$\frac{\frac{-2}{k}}{(v-\frac{1}{2k})\cdot(v+\frac{1}{2k})}=\frac{A}{v-\frac{1}{2k}}+\frac{B}{v+\frac{1}{2k}}$$
$$\frac{-8k}{(2k\cdot v-1)\cdot (2k\cdot v+1)}=\frac{2kA}{2k\cdot v-1}+\frac{2kB}{2k\cdot v+1}$$
Cross-multiply to put the system over a common denominator:
$$\frac{-8k}{(2k\cdot v-1)\cdot (2k\cdot v+1)}=\frac{2kA \cdot (2k \cdot v + 1)+ 2kB \cdot (2k \cdot v - 1)}{(2k\cdot v-1)\cdot(2k\cdot v+1)}$$
Now that we have a common denominator, we can solve just using the numerator:
$$v^0=1:-8k=2kA-2kB \rightarrow -4=A-B$$
$$v^1=v:0=4k^2A v+4k^2B v \rightarrow 0=A+B$$
Thus, the solution is:
$$A=-2,B=2$$
So the PFD expansion is:
$$\frac{\frac{-2}{k}}{(v-\frac{1}{2k})\cdot(v+\frac{1}{2k})}=\frac{-2}{v-\frac{1}{2k}}+\frac{2}{v+\frac{1}{2k}}$$

Now we can integrate this final expression. Heretofore we were manipulating the integrand:
$$\int \left(\frac{-2}{v-\frac{1}{2k}}+\frac{2}{v+\frac{1}{2k}}\right)dv$$
$$=-2\ln(v-\frac{1}{2k})+2\ln(v+\frac{1}{2k})+C$$
Now to start performing the back-substitution into the original variables:
1) $v=\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2k}$
$$=-2\ln(\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k})+2\ln(\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k})+C$$
$$=-2\ln(\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{k})+2\ln(\cos(\theta))+C$$
2) $u=\tan^2(\theta)=\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}=\frac{1-\cos^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)}-1\rightarrow \cos(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}$
$$=-2\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{1}{k} \right)+2\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}} \right)+C$$
Put both sides in place:
$$\ln(x)=-2\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{1}{k} \right)+2\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}} \right)+C$$
Now that we have both sides, we need to solve for $u$ to get the explicit form of the ODE:
$$\ln(x)=2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$
$$e^{\ln(x)}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{1}{k}}\right)^2$$
$$\sqrt{x}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{x} \cdot \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{1}{k} \right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}$$
$$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{k}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}$$
$$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{k}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}(\sqrt{x}-1)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{k}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{u+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{k\cdot (\sqrt{x}-1)}$$
$$u+1=\frac{(k\cdot (\sqrt{x}-1))^2}{x}$$
$$u=\frac{(k\cdot (\sqrt{x}-1))^2}{x}-1$$
Therefore, do the final substitution:
$$y(x)=x\cdot u(x)=(k\cdot (\sqrt{x}-1))^2-x$$

Comment: Beautiful work, indeed ! I wonder if there is not a problem during back substitution steps since the very last equation does not seem to satisfy the differential equation. For sure, I can be totally wrong ! Cheers ;-)

Comment: Again, it is so long that I can make mistakes but it seems to me that $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{k\sqrt{u^2+1}-2 u}$$. Could you check ? If I am correct, then starts a nightmare ! Cheers :-)

Comment: You are correct. Thanks a lot. Now time to start redoing the solution! :)

Comment: I can give you $$\int\frac{du}{k\sqrt{u^2+1}-2 u}=\frac{\log \left(\left(k^2-4\right) u^2+k^2\right)-2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 u}{k
   \sqrt{u^2+1}}\right)+k \sinh ^{-1}(u)}{k^2-4}$$ hoping no mistakes ! Good luck !!